# How can I query for direct descendants only?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Let's say I have entities a, b and c all of the same type, and the situation is like this:

entity a is parent for entity b
entity b is parent for entity c

Now if I do the following query

```
query = ndb.Query(ancestor=a.key)
result = query.fetch()
```

The result will contain both b and c entities. Is there a way I can filter out c so that only entities that are direct descendants remain? Any way apart from me going through the results and removing them I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to do this is to modify your schema, adding a 'parent' `KeyProperty` that references an entity's direct parent, then filtering on that.

Comment: Also note that the result of the ancestor query will in fact also contain a (assuming they all have the same kind). You could also have a 'level' property in each entity where the root has level 0, its direct children have level 1, their children level 2, and o on.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is not supported at all. Nick's answer does work but only if you can specify the entity kind in your query which the OP did not specify:

"Kindless queries cannot include filters on properties. They can, however, filter by Entity Key by passing Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY as the property name for the filter. Ascending sorts on Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY are also supported."

Comment: I'm using Nick's answer and it works fine. I had to move to the poly model though.

Comment: @sorin7486 So, are you saying you've been successful doing an ancestor query that includes a filter but does NOT include the kind?

Comment: It does contain a kind, just that it's the base kind. All my objects are different types of pages and they all extend a Page class.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late, however it will help anyone with the same problem.

The solution is to first do a keys-only query and take the subset of keys which are direct descendants.

With that subset of keys, you can batch get the desired entities.

I'm unfamiliar with python, so here's an example in go:

```
directDescKeys := make([]*datastore.Key, 0)

q := datastore.NewQuery("A").Ancestor(parentKey).KeysOnly()
for it := q.Run(ctx);; {
    key, err := it.Next(nil)
    if err == datastore.Done {
        break
    } else if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }

    if reflect.DeepEquals(key.Parent(), parentKey) {
        directDescKeys = append(directDescKeys, key)
    }
}

entities := make([]*A, len(directDescKeys))
if err := datastore.GetMulti(ctx, directDescKeys, entities); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```