# Is there a limit to how many Ancestors an Entity can have?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to set an existing (Item) entity as the parent of another kind (rating) of entity. So I can let my users rate items.

At the moment the Item entity has an ancestor with an ancestor etc. of different kinds as shown below. In scenario 1 the Item entity cannot be found to be entered as a parent to the Rating. But in scenario 2 it works swimmingly.

```
Scenario 1                                       Scenario 2
 Category
    v
  Aisle
    v
  Group
    v
  Type
    v
  Item >>>>> getKey()                   Item >>>>> getKey()
                v                                     v
              Rating                                Rating
```

Please help! When the item has no ancestors it works fine, but when it has all the ancestors I need it to have it doesn't work!!!

Here's the code I'm using.

```
 DatastoreService datastoreService = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
int rating = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("rating"));                                 
String type = req.getParameter("type");                                                    
String raterid = req.getParameter("rater");                                                
String target =  req.getParameter("target");                                               
Key k = KeyFactory.createKey("Item", Long.parseLong(target));
Entity trgt = null;
try {
    trgt =  datastoreService.get(k);
} catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
  Key k = KeyFactory.("Item", target);
Key r;
String raterkind;
if (type=="user"){
    raterkind = "Deliverer";
}
else  {raterkind = "Customer";}
r = KeyFactory.createKey(raterkind,raterid);
Entity ratingentity = null;
if (trgt != null) {
    ratingentity = new Entity("rating",trgt.getKey());
}
else {
    ratingentity = new Entity("rating",k);
}
ratingentity.setProperty("target",k);
ratingentity.setProperty("rating",rating);
ratingentity.setProperty("rater",r);
datastoreService.put(ratingentity);
```

Here are some pictures to show what's happening.
[image]

These are the Item Entities.

[image]

As you can see, this Item is simple, without any extra ancestor Keys. And you can see below it works.

[image]

And this is the one with the parents/acestors.

[image]

As you can see below, it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Have you read this?: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/contention?hl=en  In particular, the part about keeping entity groups small.

Comment: You'll need to show some code - how are you trying to get retrieve the `Item`?  Also your question is unclear: you say *the Item entity has multiple ancestors* - it has *one* ancestor, a `Type`, which in turn has another ancestor.  An entity can have only one direct ancestor.

Comment: Also, this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33000904/ancestor-query-direct-descendants-google-datastore/33010769

Comment: ok I've had a look at the docs, I guess I was naive to think that I could introduce this level over ancestry without any problems @Kekito.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other post @tx802 , It makes a good point, maybe I don't need so many levels above the actual item. The idea of having a single kind called parentCategory makes sense. Would I still be able to keep this level of ancestry and avoid the issues if they're all of the same kind?

Comment: @user2664050 I'm not sure what you're asking but ancestor keys (i) can be of any Kind and (ii) don't event have to exist as entities.

Comment: I did not know (ii), I will try this again without making the ancestors into entities. @tx802

Comment: ok That didn't work @tx802. It seems that if I have any ancestors, entity or not, on the item, the rating will not link back to the item.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
String target =  req.getParameter("target");                                               
Key k = KeyFactory.createKey("Item", Long.parseLong(target));
```

This will give you the key for *an* Item with a `long` id of whatever the value of `target` is.  It is probably not the `Item` you are looking for.

Assuming your `trgt` is mean to be the `Item` in scenario one, you cannot retrieve it by id alone - you need the full key path of `Category > Aisle > Group > Type > Item` as IDs are unique only within an entity group.

Also, your `raterkind` will always be `"Customer"` - [you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324629/simple-string-comparison-question)

```
if (type.equals("user")) {...}
```

instead of

```
if (type=="user") {...}
```

Comment: Thanks for the == thing. I see what you're saying about getting the whole key. I made one Item property to show its own key and it came out to be Key('Category', 'FoodCupboard', 'Aisle', 'RPN', 'Group', 'Rice', 'Type', 'Basmati', 'Item', 5649050225344512)    How do I get it to find the key from within any entity group?

Comment: I just ended up changing the item as the main Entity. Thanks for your help though.